# Accessing XAML from code properly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm just getting started with Xamarin.Forms and I'm not finding any documentation that specifies how I manipulate something like the text in a Label from code. I just have an application with a Label, a plus button and a minus button. Plus should increment the value in the Label and minus should do the opposite.

My view is defined in XAML. When I look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/ then I don't really find something that matches this. I guess that I should create a "NumberViewModel" that represents the number, then use some PropertyChanged-isch system to bind the data to the view.

If this was Android then I would define my buttons in xml with the expected names of the methods that will handle a button-click(I do the same in Xamarin.Forms). Then the button is clicked then the method in code will be triggered and in the triggered method I will probably retrieve the object I wish to manipulate by calling findViewById(....).

I will adjust to Xamarin.Forms but it would be great with a simple guide that just showes how to bind a string to a label, without hundreds of lines of code. Please tell me that I am just bad at googling, because I've spend a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two approaches you can go here: the easier, but uglier one, and the little bit more complex, but prettier one.

**Directly editing the code behind**

*(Easier, but uglier due to high coupling)*

Say we would have the following XAML:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label x:Name="lblOutput" Text="[output]" />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Text="+" />
        <Button x:Name="btnMinus" Text="-" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

You can reference the UI directly in the code behind like so (simplified):

```
int currentValue = 0;
lblOutput.Text = currentValue.ToString ();
btnAdd.Clicked += delegate {
    currentValue++;
    lblOutput.Text = currentValue.ToString ();
};

btnMinus.Clicked += delegate {
    currentValue--;
    lblOutput.Text = currentValue.ToString ();
};
```

The trick here is the use of `x:Name`, allowing you to directly use the element in the code behind.

**Using the MVVM approach**

*(More complex, but more flexible)*

Create a new class (your ViewModel) and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Bind that class to the view in the XAML code behind like so:

```
this.BindingContext = new ViewModel ();
```

Now we can have a XAML like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Text="{Binding CurrentValue}" />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Text="+" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
        <Button Text="-" Command="{Binding MinusCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and the ViewModel would look like this:

```
public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }
public ICommand MinusCommand { get; private set; }

public ViewModel ()
{
    AddCommand = new Command (() => {
        CurrentValue = CurrentValue+1;
    });

    MinusCommand = new Command (() => {
        CurrentValue = CurrentValue-1;
    });
}

public int CurrentValue { get; set; } // You'll need to handle the PropertyChanged events here
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Was about to answer the same thing +1

Comment: Thanks!!! Maybe I should have mentioned that I usually work with Java, so concepts like field-backing properties(even though you don't have them here) and the event keyword are not very familiar to me. Perfect example, thanks again.